# Help! Need offline capable music to ward off demons, spirits, and other things in the mind and body

Tags: catholicism, demons, demon-possession, supernatural, pastoral-care

Demons and seemingly ancient manifestations are attacking me and I'm all alone and have no help and no family that believes in this effect I'm having.

Even my Catholic father and Protestant mother. Nobody is there for me, and they renounced their faith in various ways and they never go to Church. I'm looking for refuge and looking across the United States for anything. Where can I go (ideas?)

I need music to hear, my real true question. An app on the App Store or anything I can wear headphones or play without the internet.

In all truth and honesty, the streaming aspect of Cellular networks and Wifi seems to cause more effect on my spirit and soul in a negative way because the demons of technology are AGAINST me. Please help me find a way to get offline and off the internet in a way that won't allow them to find me. HELP HELP HELP Pray God please have mercy on my soul. I said I want to "HELP PEOPLE", and the demon "HA" changed it to "HELL PEOPLE".

I'm only a human, never a God, and they are vicious ancient spirits, and the only defense I can find is FM radio in some parts of the US that seems to work better than others.

I'm living in hotels trying to find a place away from Cellular, Wifi, and GPS that allow the demons from hell to find me (I'm a good guy computer hacker and they attack me due to my interaction with Bitcoin). BEWARE of the spiritual trampoline of the internet shared with darkness, the resonance created is equal to the destruction of the [this bridge](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bridge%20video%20wind%20old) but has spiritual properties that affect our soul. (s

Comment: @PeterTurner You found a man in need of help, sent him a URL to click on, and closed off all other possibly of help. I'm beyond desperate. May you never know the situation I'm in nor the desperation of my need. MAY THE ANGELS SCREAM AT YOU THAT THE EGO OF Administration AND THE DIAMOND NEXT TO YOUR NAME has made you a heartless Pharisee. IGNORANT FOOL I CALL YOU IN THE GLORIOUS NAME OF CHRIST. May God have mercy on you and your soul

Comment: Your troubles are too important to speak to anonymous people on the internet. Please speak to a senior Christian you trust in person.

Comment: I have nobody, and need direction. I spent my life raising my brother and supporting my family financially, I'm 44 and have nobody to assist now that is over (my little brother is supporting them, and I'm broke, with no escrow of any safety)... I have nowhere to turn. I'm being the good guy they want to imposter in heaven because I'm such an easy target. I'm protestant and that isn't as organized as catholic. My dad abandoned us and calls us "tragic". HE abandoned us 40 years ago. I'm being spiritually framed with nowhere to turn. Demon attacks and ancient attacks it seems, dear @curiousdannii

Comment: Are there churches near you? Almost all churches will be very eager to talk to anyone with needs and concerns like you.

Comment: @halfbit God bless you hope it works out. Derek Prince has some great and practical messages on youtube discussing unclean and evil spirits.

Comment: Even medical doctors, whose care is mainly directed at the human body, do not allow self-diagnoses and self-medicating, since these acts are oftentimes dangerous, leading to physical demise. The same holds true in the spiritual realm as well, especially when it comes to such (self)labels as possession.

Comment: Play [Gregorian chant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2eogtzV0MI&list=PL1b_YGxGPhrLqKTWX8QeqTMI6J_DYG1xD).

Comment: Thank you @Geremia I downloaded them using Parallels Toolbox and put them onto my phone using VLC player. I now have something I can use offline, off the internet, without any demons hitting my body using Wifi or Cellular. Thank you. I have the strength to login and say thank you. The demons are real, and beyond what we know of as life. Ancient spells from evil somewhere on the Internet (attacking me because I'm an easy target). Peace and be well. I hope others similarly affected find these comments

Comment: @halfbit Here are [the vespers hymns for today's feast of St. Dominic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NRmSuSdiJ0&list=PL-edc4nsbneXhYz6ZF0eO5Zq9YNex5V9o).